# What is the analogue of GENERATE_SERIES from Postgres in Presto?

Tags: sql, presto

I want to write this query in Presto:

```
    SELECT
        * 
    FROM (
        SELECT GENERATE_SERIES(0, 30) days
    )
```

But it says that function GENERATE_SERIES doesn't exist in Presto. What can I use instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`sequence`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/array.html#sequence) with `unnest`:

```sql
SELECT days
FROM (SELECT sequence(0, 30) as d)
CROSS JOIN UNNEST (d) as t(days)
```

Comment: thx, but I then select it:  ``` SELECT
        * 
    FROM (
        SELECT GENERATE_SERIES(0, 30) days
    ) AS ...```  And with your query it won't work

Comment: @french_fries can you explain what exactly does not work for you with the provided query? You can use the whole query as subselect in yours.

Comment: with my example I can do this:    SELECT
        * 
    FROM (
        SELECT SEQUENCE(0, 30) days
    ) as q1                                                                                                                        But not with yours. this: ```SELECT days
FROM (SELECT sequence(0, 30) as d)
CROSS JOIN UNNEST (d) as t(days)  as q1```   brings error

Comment: @french_fries then you do `SELECT * FROM (SELECT days
FROM (SELECT sequence(0, 30) as d)
CROSS JOIN UNNEST (d) as t(days) ) as q1` . What is the problem? The whole query is meant to be used as analog of `GENERATE_SERIES`